# applescript for Adobe acrobat pro - running action from action wizard

Tags: applescript, acrobat

I have a doubt in adobe acrobat pro..

I m using applescript to run a action from `Adobe acrobat Pro => Tools => "action wizard"`.

actually it does only the first step in choosing the action "Rajni" from the action wizard,

but i cant click the button "Next" seen in the window, to go to the next step... and then click close button....

could any body help on this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Acrobat"
        tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro" to activate
        click the menu item "Rajni" of menu 1 of menu item "Action Wizard" of the menu "File" of menu bar 1
        click button "Next" of window "Action: Rajni" -- here is the problem ........
    end tell
end tell
```

Many thanks...

Comment: You can use the Record feature of the Automator application to record the UI interaction steps necessary for this workflow. Then you can then literally select and copy the recorded steps in automator and paste them into a new Applescript Editor window. This will give you applescript which may or may not work. You'll probably want to edit the script, but at least it should help give an idea what else might be needed to do this programatically.  I don't have access to Acrobat Pro, so can't give a specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

try to add some delay before clicking window.

```
click the menu item "Rajni" of menu 1 of menu item "Action Wizard" of the menu "File" of menu bar 1
delay 2
click button "Next" of window "Rajni"
```